# Is it possible to integrate a third-party library into a smart contract using ink!

Tags: ink, runtime, smart-contract, chain-extension

I want to integrate a third party library into my ink! smart contract and I am not sure if this is possible. I did notice that ink! has something called Chain Extensions which can allow a smart contract to interact with the runtime and I am wondering if there is a way to add the third party library to the runtime as a pallet and then interact with it using the smart contract. Is this feasible or are there any other ways I can go about doing something like this?

Edit: I want to mention that the library I want to integrate supports no-std.

Comment: I advise you to use http://openbrush.io. amazing framework for smart contract development with ink!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can treat ink! contract as any other rust application - you can add dependencies to your `Cargo.toml` file and use these dependencies across your project, however, these libraries need to enable usage of no-standard Rust library.